# Why CSS font-size doesn't change?

Tags: html, css

```css
.navbar-brand{
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Ubuntu";
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}
```

```html
<a class="navbar-brand" href="">tindog</a>
```

So this is how I try to change the font-size for my link through a certain class and I came across something strange that everything has changed whether it is font-family or font-weight which means that I define the class in index.html correctly and in the css file I am doing it right!!
But the size does not change, someone explain to me what could be the problem.
THANKS!!

Comment: try adding [!important](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp)

Comment: Using important it's not a good idea, better search what is overwriting your rule with css specifity

Comment: navbar-brand sounds like you are using some css library? do you use bootstrap? Is this library declaring styles with higher priority for this element regarding font-size?

Comment: The code you have given does not illustrate the problem. Have a look to find exactly what is setting the CSS by using your browsers dev tools inspect facility.

Answer (score -1):

I tested your code and there is nothing wrong with it. Try to change the font size using pixels instead.

```
.navbar-brand {
font-weight: bold;
font-family: "Ubuntu";
font-size: 40px;
}
```

Since 1rem = 16px.

Comment: He probably only has sules with greater specificity

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```css
.navbar-brand{
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Ubuntu";
  font-size: 2.5rem !important;
}
```